# How can I add a line into a text file next to specific word in bash?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to add line to a text file next to a word `users:`

This is my file.txt:

```
users:
  - angel
```

This is, what I do is to replace the word `users:` with same `users:` and the username `- rick` (`users: - rick`):

```
sed -i -e 's/users:/users: - rick/g' file.text
```

This is what I get:

```
users: - rick
  - angel
```

But if I continue adding users:

```
users: - mike - rick
      - angel
```

Is there a way to append to next line like?:

```
users: 
  - mike
  - rick
  - angel
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thinking on the fly here but I think this will work

```
sed -i -e 's/users:/users: \n - rick/g' file.text
```

Can confirm it works;

```
λ sed -i -e 's/users:/users: \n - mark/g' file.text
λ cat file.text
users:
 - mark
 - rick
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this via:

```
sed -i -e 's/users:/& \' -e '  - rick/g' file.text
```

or...

```
sed -i -e '/users:/s/$/\' -e '  - rick/' file.text
```

This should insert the new name after the `users:` string, but before the other names.

Comment: it says ``sed: -e expression #1, char 13: unterminated `s' command`` thank you for you answer l'L'l.